# A property of concave functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions

The function $\sqrt x$ is obviously concave. Assume that $f(x)$ is a continuous function $\mathbb{R_+}\to\mathbb{R_+}$ that is asymptotically bigger than $\sqrt x$, that is 
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty }\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt x}=+\infty.
$$

Is it always possible to find a **concave** function $g(x)$ that would be between $f(x)$ and $\sqrt x$? Formally I want $g(x)\le f(x)$ for all positive $x$ and 
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty }\frac{g(x)}{\sqrt x}=+\infty.
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly is $f$ defined and is it assumed to be continuous? If $f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$: There is some $x_0\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $f(x)\geq 2\sqrt{x}$ for all $x\geq x_0$. Now take $g(x)=2\sqrt{x}+C$ where $C=\min(0,\min_{x\in [0,x_0]} f(x)-2\sqrt{x})$

Comment: @Uncountable thanks for you comment. Unfortunately such $g$ would not work, since we have the condition that $g(x)/\sqrt x\to\infty$, that is the function $g$ is really between $f$ and $\sqrt x$.

Comment: Yes you are right... This turns out to be harder than expected. I do think we need $f$ to be continuous: If $f$ is not assumed to be continuous then we can take $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1/(x-1)\mbox{ if } 0\leq x<1\\ 0\mbox{ if } x=1\\ x \mbox{ if } x\geq 1\end{cases}$$ and then $g$ (which has to be increasing) cannot have a finite value in, say, $1/2$.

Comment: In your example one can just take $g(x)=x-1$, this should work, right?

Comment: No, since then $f(1/2)=-2<-1/2=g(1/2)$ (note that $f$ diverges to $-\infty$ as $x$ tends to $1$ from the left)

Comment: I agree. We can safely assume that $f$ is continuous and positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume wlog that $f(x)\geq \sqrt x $ (otherwise apply a vertical translation). Construct (the graph of) $g$ in the following sketched way: start following the profile of $\sqrt x$ until the point $x_1$ after which $f(x)$ stays eventually above $2\sqrt x$ (or in any case follow the profile for, say, one unit of length); at this point follow the tangent line to $ \sqrt x$ at $x_1$ until you hit the graph of $2\sqrt x$. Now follow the graph of $2\sqrt x$ until the point $x_2$ after which $f(x)$ stays eventually above $3\sqrt x$ (or, say, for one unit); at this point follow the tangent line to $ 2\sqrt x$ at $x_2$ until you hit the graph of $3\sqrt x$, and so on.

The function thus constructed is concave because every time you hit the next graph, you hit it "from below", by the concavity of $n\sqrt x$. It stays under $f$ because it does at each step. And clearly it will be asymptotically large wrt to $\sqrt x$.

Comment: Del, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Oleg You're welcome!